# Android TCP connection receiving packets out of order

Tags: android, tcp, wifi, microcontroller

I have a Particle Photon microcontroller sending TCP packets over a hotspot WiFi network to an Android Phone. The microcontroller is acting as server, the phone as client.

The phone however is receiving some (but not all) of the packets out of order, despite the information being transmitted via tcp. It was my understanding that this would not happen - am i wrong, or is there something i can do to correct this?

Microcontroller Code:

```
// This #include statement was automatically added by the Particle IDE.
#include "databuffer5.h"

// This #include statement was automatically added by the Particle IDE.
#include "databuffer7.h"





const unsigned int localPort = 10000;
IPAddress remoteIP(a, b, c, d);
// An TCP instance to let us send and receive packets over wifi
TCPServer server = TCPServer(localPort);
TCPClient client;

// UDP Port used for two way communication


short msg_count = 0;

const int adcPin = A0; 


int byteBuffer;

unsigned long loopTimer;

const int packetSize = 40;  //number of bytes in packet - 10 ints with 4 bytes each
byte buffer[packetSize]; 

int j = 0;
int dataCount = 0;  //dummy data that increments every loop point, to measure packet contiuity 
                    //(creates a line with slope 1 as data)





void setup() {
  // start the UDP
  server.begin();


  // Print your device IP Address via serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); 
  //Serial.println(System.ticksPerMicrosecond());   //returns 120, ie 120MHz


}



void loop() 
{
  if (client.connected())
  {
    loopTimer = millis();  //mark start time of loop

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {



          //for testing connection
          byteBuffer = i+j*10;

          buffer[i*4]   = ( (byteBuffer  >> 24) & 0xFF);     //take upper 8 bits  
          buffer[i*4+1] = ( (byteBuffer  >> 16) & 0xFF);     //take middle upper 8 bits  
          buffer[i*4+2] = ( (byteBuffer  >> 8 ) & 0xFF);     //take middle lower 8 bits 
          buffer[i*4+3] = (  byteBuffer         & 0xFF);     //take lower 8 bits
          dataCount++;

          if (i != 9) 
          {
              while(millis() < (loopTimer+10*(i+1)));  //ie do nothing for 10 ms (time is in ms, want to delay by exactly 10ms for each loop)

                                                        //goal here is to sample every 10ms, by delaying for the remaining time 
                                                        //dont delay here for the last sample, as the udp packet will take time
                                                        //delay after instead
          }

      }


      server.write(buffer, sizeof(buffer)); //using sizeof on a byte array so dont need to scale (ie scaling factor is 1)
      j++; 
      if (j < 0){j = 0;}
      while(millis() < (loopTimer+10*10));  //delay till 100ms after loops started
   }
   else 
   {
       client = server.available();
   }
}
```

Android (client) code:

```
async_udp = new AsyncTask<Void, int[], Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


                byte b1[];
                b1 = new byte[100];

                while (serverActive) {
                    Socket socket = null;   //previously this was DatagramSocket (UDP) - no Socket (TCP)
                    try {
                        //DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(server_port, server_ip);
                        socket = new Socket(server_ip, server_port);
                        socket.setPerformancePreferences(1, 2, 2);

                        InputStream socketStream = socket.getInputStream();



                        DatagramPacket p1 = new DatagramPacket(b1, b1.length);


                        ByteBuffer wrapped;
                        int data[] = new int[10+1];  //first number for message data, second is for the message number

                        while (serverActive)   //TODO include shutdown function
                        {
                            while (socketStream.available() < 39){}

                            socketStream.read(b1, 0, 40);

                            //packet structure is a char containing message number, and 10  shorts (2 bytes) containing data points (between 0 and 4096)


                            wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(b1, 0, 40)); // extract 40 bytes to convert to 10 ints
                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                data[i] = wrapped.getInt();
                            }


                            String str = data.toString();

                            server_port = p1.getPort();
                            server_ip = p1.getAddress();


                            String str_msg = "RECEIVED FROM CLIENT IP =" + server_ip + " port=" + server_port + " message no = " + b1[0] +
                                    " data=" + str;  //first character is message number


                            statusText = str_msg;
                            publishProgress(data);

                        }
                        socketStream.close();
                        socket.close();

                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                        if (socket != null) {}

                        //status.append("Error creating socket");
                        statusText = (" Error creating socket");   //this doesn't work!
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //status.append("Error recieving packet");
                        statusText = (" Error receiving packet");  //this doesn't work!
                    }
                    try{
                    Thread.sleep(100, 0);  //sleep for 10ms if no wifi lock is found, to stop battery being silly
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(int[]... data1)
            {
                super.onProgressUpdate(data1);
                int data[] = data1[0];

                //send data to graph

                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastDataX++, data[i]), false, graphPointsMax);
                    //append 9 points to graph, but only redraw the grpah on the 10th
                }
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastDataX++, data[9]), true, graphPointsMax);



            }

        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        {
            async_udp.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
        else
        {
            async_udp.execute();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

What is guaranteed by TCP, is that when you send a message - it will come in the right order, even if split by the TCP stack along the way (see TCP Segment Number, which serves as an indication which split message part belongs together with which, and in what order). So, in your case, all you are sending using:

> server.write(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

no meter how big is the buffer (within the limits of TCP protocol, of course) is guaranteed to arrive in the right order and complete.

Sending several buffers one-by-one over TCP will provide you guaranteed delivery, or error notification (if any), but not the order of the messages sent. Down to the protocol level, these packets will contain different [Sequence Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure), and therefore will be treated by the TCP stack of the receiver separately, in the order the stack prefers.

I see two relatively simple things that could be done here:

1. try to put all you can in one buffer (not really practical approach, though)
2. Introduce the counter and increment each time you are sending the buffer out. Put the counter along with the buffer and check the precedence on the receiving side (phone, in your case).

Comment: Option 1is no good for me as I'm trying to reduce latency as much as possible. Are there any standard libraries/solutions for option 2? I tried implementing it myself but being a self taught programmer i didnt quite have the skills to do it in the time i had

Comment: This answer is completely wrong! TCP doesn't care about "messages" at the top end, it is completely stream oriented and guarantees the correct order of all received bytes (or communication failure). See paragraph 5 of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Network_function. I have no idea why the OP is having problems but this is not the reason.

Comment: @DoxyLover - you are right about TCP having nothing to do with messages (in terms of OSI model). I just tried to use the terminology of the topic starter. By messages in my answer one should understand separate packets (or parts of a stream, if you prefer to generalize it). To the post owner - any luck trying what I have suggested?

Comment: @OpalApps Yes, "on the wire" packets may be in any order. However, this doesn't matter to the user-livel code. TCP will reassemble the incoming packets to guarantee that at the user level, you will receive all bytes in the order sent, regardless of how the user-level sender packaged the data. It doesn't matter if it writes a byte at a time or 10,000 bytes at once. This is the basis of TCP and if Android or the sending micro doesn't do this, one of them is broken (and I don't think it's Android)!

Comment: @DoxyLover, Agree. And I would suspect that the library on the micro's side mixes the order. But from how the problem sounds - the assembly of the stream happens on the Android side. It could be that library on MCU side ignores the sequence numbers or inserts them incorrectly. Dump of the traffic would help to tell more.

Comment: @OpalApps I never received a notification on these as they aren't comments on my post. I had no progress, and kind of ignored it and moved on. My running theory is that it nis indeed android that is casuing the issue - the thread is lagging or something and missing a packet, causing one to be repeated several times. I haven't really had time to test it though.